# Is there a generalization for "planar graph" for any dimension?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

We have the definition of planar graph, which captures the idea of all the connections "lying in a plane." Because any graph can be embedded in three-dimensional space without crossing, this definition does not generalize. However, there is a definition of a graph "lying in a volume-space" which is the definition of a linklessly embeddable graph.

So we have:

1-dimension :: path graph (embeddable in a line)

2-dimension :: planar graph (embeddable in a plane)

3-dimension :: linklessly embeddable graph (embeddable in space)

What are the generalizations for $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Something that might interest you is the genus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory) of a graph. This is a measure of how non-planar a graph is and might help expand your understanding of "dimensions" of a graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The generalization is the [Colin de Verdière graph invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_de_Verdi%C3%A8re_graph_invariant) ($\mu$). We have the following cases.

1. $\mu \leq 1$ :: path graph or disjoint union of path graphs.
2. $\mu \leq 2$ :: outerplanar graph
3. $\mu \leq 3$ :: planar graph
4. $\mu \leq 4$ :: linklessly embeddable graph

The "$\leq$" is only necessary because any outerplanar graph is a planar graph, and is a linklessly embeddable graph, and so on. If we set $\mu = 3$ we get the strict planar graphs, excluding outerplanar graphs and path graphs (or their disjoint unions).